# How to check if a ticket is still open or has been closed?

Tags: mql4

If I open a position with `OrderSend` setting a *take profit*  and a *stop loss*, how can I check if it is still open or, on the contrary, it has been closed because of the *stop_loss* or the *take profit*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you must have ticketId that you received when you send OrderSend() request.
In order to figure out whether the trade is open or not, use the following:

```
 int ticket; //your ticket from OrderSend in global variables
 bool isOrderExist(const int _ticket){
    if(OrderSelect(_ticket,SELECT_BY_TICKET)){
       return(OrderCloseTime()==0);
    }else{
       int error=GetLastError();
       return(error!=4108 && error!=4051);
    }
 }
```

In order to check if the order is closed by SL or TP or any other reason - you should select the order from the `OrdersHistory()` and then check comment (often '[sl]' or '[tp]' is added to comment) or compare close price and SL and TP

Comment: just a note: [sl] is added to the comment even if a stop profit is hit. So if you want to detect if a SL was hit (i.e. the order closed with a loss) you should check if the OrderProfit() is <0

Answer (score 1):

You could probably also use: `OrderPrint()`:

```cpp
if(OrderSelect(10, SELECT_BY_TICKET)==true) 
    OrderPrint(); 
else 
    Print("OrderSelect failed error code is",GetLastError());
```

From the MetaEditor Reference:

> Prints information about the selected order in the log in the following format:

```
ticket number; 
open time; 
trade operation; 
amount of lots; 
symbol; 
open price; 
Stop Loss; 
Take Profit; 
close time; 
close price; 
commission; 
swap; 
profit; 
comment; 
magic number; 
pending order expiration date.
```